# Woes using urllib.request.urlretrieve. Saves as HTML file?

Tags: python, urllib

New (newb) python user here! Quick question, hopefully basic level, working with
urllib.request.urlretrieve. I can't figure out why the below code returns an HTML file (saved as a .zip) instead of an actual zip file. Any help would be extremely appreciated!!!

```
import os 
import zipfile 
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://www.kaggle.com/annavictoria/speed-dating-experiment/downloads/"
SPEED_PATH = "datasets/speed"
SPEED_URL =  DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "speed-dating-experiment.zip"

def fetch_speed_data(speed_url=SPEED_URL, speed_path=SPEED_PATH):
        if not os.path.isdir(speed_path):
            os.makedirs(speed_path)
        zip_path = os.path.join(speed_path, "speed.zip")
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(speed_url, zip_path)
        speed_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'a')
        speed_zip.extractall(path=speed_path)
        speed_zip.close()

fetch_speed_data()
```

Comment: Presumably because the server served you a HTML page. Any hints as to what the HTML page says? Some servers filter on scripted clients to prevent scraping.

Comment: Looks like a login page to me; presumably they want you to be authenticated first before downloading.